# Laravel 8 undefined variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am getting the following error.

> ErrorException Undefined variable $brands (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\wearwearemv\resources\views\backend\brand\brand_view.blade.php)
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/brand/view

I could not figure out what is wrong here. Any help?

Here is my route

```
Route::get('/brand/view', [BrandController::class, 'BrandView'])->name('all.brands');
```

Controller function

```
public function BrandView()
{
    $brands = Brand::latest()->get();

    return view('backend.brand.brand_view', compact($brands));
}
```

And my forloop

```
<tbody>
   @foreach($brands as $item)
   <tr>
     <td>{{ $item->brand_name }}</td>
     <td><img src="{{ asset($item->brand_image) }}" style="width: 70px; height: 40px;"></td>
     <td>
       <a href="" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
       <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
     </td>
    </tr>
   @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compact function expects strings with variable names:

```
return view('backend.brand.brand_view', compact('brands'));
```

Comment: (facepalm) Thank you very much.

Comment: A mistake everyone makes sometimes :-D, You're welcome